# Mapbox uploading background image

Tags: mapbox, cartocss

I'm trying to change the background of my map and put an image instead of it.

I'm currently using map box studio so when I'm choosing a local path 
(c\deskstop\toto.png), it is working on the software, so if I choose to upload my whole map style, and use my map on the internet, it doesn't work.

I choose to upload the picture in my website then I changed the URL of the path too ( toto.com\pictures\toto.png). but it is till not working

Does someone has already this problem with mapbox?

Comment: Do you have any code snippet that you are using?

Comment: thanks you for asking, im just stupid actually i had to put my image where all the configurations file are